# Java Inheritance with Lambdas

Tags: java, inheritance, lambda

I'm trying to make it so that a superclass (abstract or interface) is the reference type in an ArrayList (which define a null lambda)... and the sub-classes which implement that superclass/interface have different lambda expressions to shadow the superclass's null lambda. But what ends up happening is, calling the sub-class lambda only calls the superclass's null lambda!

Example code:

```
public abstract class AbstractAction {
    Consumer<AbstractAction> behavior = state -> {
        System.out.println("AbstractAction: do nothing");
    };
}
public class IfTrue extends AbstractAction {
    Boolean var = true;
    Consumer<IfTrue> behavior = state -> {
        if (state.var == true) state.var = false;
        System.out.println("IfTrue: " + var);
    };
}
public class Compare extends AbstractAction {
    Boolean var1 = true;
    Boolean var2 = true;

    Consumer<Compare> behavior = state -> {
        if (state.var1 == state.var2) state.var1 = false;
        System.out.println("IfTrue: " + var1 + " " + var2);
    };
}
public class ActionList {
    List<AbstractAction> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addAction(AbstractAction abstractAction) {
        list.add(abstractAction);
    }

    public void runActions() {
        for (AbstractAction a : list) {
            a.behavior.accept(a);
        }
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ActionList list = new ActionList();
        list.addAction(new IfTrue());
        list.addAction(new Compare());
        list.runActions();
    }
}
```

The Result (shows the AbstractAction lambda is being run, not the sub-classes):

```
AbstractAction: do nothing
AbstractAction: do nothing
```

But I expected to see:

```
IfTrue: true
Compare: false true
```

I also tried making an Interface, but then I can't have different numbers of member variables in each subclass, otherwise I get compile time errors that Actionable interface doesn't have those members. But even if I do give the Actionable interface those variables, I get the same result. The Actionable.behavior lambda is run instead of the subclass implementations.

```
public interface Actionable {
    Boolean var = true;
    Boolean var1 = true;
    Boolean var2 = true;

    Consumer<Actionable> behavior = state -> {
        System.out.println("AbstractAction: do nothing");
    };
}
```

Is there no way to shadow the AbstractAction or Actionable.behavior lambda? Or am I thinking about this problem all wrong? I really want to be able to swap out Action objects with different behaviors/lambdas to decouple the actions from the execution process itself.

Comment: I don't understand why you are using lambdas and `Consumer` at all. Can't `behaviour` just be a _method_ instead? And why does it even take a parameter if you are doing `a.behavior.accept(a);` anyway? Do you ever plan on giving it anything other than itself? If so, how can you be sure that what you are giving it is the correct type?

Comment: @Sweeper yes I should have mentioned why… I have attempted my approach with instance methods, but in my application, every method call was adding milliseconds to my execution time, when the business case for this requires execution time be as fast as possible. And the reason I pass the subclass itself as parameter is so that I can have as many members as I want on each subclass, and don’t have to worry about the different quantity of parameters needed to invoke each subclasses behavior.accept() in ActionList.runActions() for loop.

Comment: Umm… how’s lambdas going to help with that? If any case, I would think lambdas have a bit _more_ overhead. Are you sure _this_ is your bottleneck out of all the things your program does?

Comment: Perhaps it’s not. I assumed Lambdas invokeDynamic or a static method for behavior would reduce GC activity and time spent instantiating an instance method every time ActionList.runActions() has to run (which may need to get as fast as every .01 milliseconds). Can you think of another approach? I know this is kind of like the Command pattern, but I’m trying to minimize on method calls.

Comment: Lambdas are basically methods on an anonymous synthetic class. Making a thing a lambda very much does not eliminate a method call; it just hides it somewhere else. If your use case is so processor-intensive that the existence of *method calls* is a bottleneck, then you shouldn't be using Java; you should be using C. Popular video games have been written in Java, and you better believe things like Minecraft have a *ton* of method calls in them every frame.

Comment: Thank you @SilvioMayolo. That data helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only instance methods can be overridden. Instance variables can never be overridden. If you have an instance variable in a subclass with the same name as an instance variable in a superclass, it will simply hide the instance variable from the superclass from the perspective of code in the subclass. But they still exist as two separate variables, and every instance of the subclass will still contain two separate instance variables. Code that uses the superclass type to refer to the instance will still be able to use it to refer to the superclass instance variable.

Of course, you could just keep the one instance variable in the superclass, and in the subclass constructor or instance initializer, you can just assign to that instance variable from the superclass (instead of declaring a new instance variable in the subclass). I still don't know whether this design make sense though.

Comment: Okay good. Makes sense. Nice tip on referencing to the superclass.